# jQuery: Set Horizontal Scrollbar in the Middle to Enable Scrolling to the Left

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

The website I'm working on has a wide main content block that doesn't fully fit inside the smaller resolution screen.

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

I want to use jQuery to force the horizontal scrollbar to appear scrolled to the middle, so that a user who has a smaller resolution screen can scroll to the left and access the menu that would otherwise be hidden.

I would be grateful for the expertly advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin, you can say: `$(...).scrollTo( '50%', {axis: 'x'} );`

Comment: Thanks Mrchief. A question: wouldn't it be the same as saying $(...).scrollLeft(50);?

Comment: Not exactly. With `scrollLeft` you're moving it by `50px`. So you need to calculate the proper value for different screen sizes if you want to move it to the middle. The plugin just makes it easy as it does all the calculation for you. Plus you can do so much more with it.

Comment: Mrchief, it's a nice plugin and I applied it, but either I don't quite understand how to use it, or it's not meant to do what I want. Could you please take a look at my site again and see what the plugin now does?

Comment: It's scrolling to the middle but I think you want it scroll so that the `main` `div` is visible, right? If yes, then instead of '50%', use: `jQuery('#main').offset().left`. Either `jQuery(document).scrollLeft(jQuery('#main').offset().left)` or `jQuery(document).scrollTo(jQuery('#main').offset().left, {axis: 'x'})` will work.

Comment: Thank you Mrchief. Actually, I want it to scroll so that #access element is visible (that is, the navigation menu attached to the left of the container). How would I need to modify the code to make it work?

Comment: The problem is, there seems to be no place to scroll.

Comment: Use `jQuery('#access')...` :)

Comment: I tried that of course. Nothing happens. Same with any other id.

Comment: Well (to fix 'no space to scroll' issue), that is a bigger problem. You need to redesign your css styles for that. Google for fluid layouts and you'll find plenty examples.

Comment: Thank you Mrchief. That's just what I ended up doing. As a result, I realized I no longer need to center the scrollbar – however, I'm very glad that I learned about the scrollTo plugin from you. It's a useful addition to my bag of tricks. Thanks again!